# Button with an icon CSS

Tags: html, css, button, icons

I created a simple login (via Gmail) button with green color. 
Look at this, please

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.button:icon {
    background: url(gmail-icon.png) no-repeat;
    float: left;
    width: 10px;
    height: 40px;
}    
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button class="button"><span class="icon"></span>Button</button>

</body>
```

But I can't see my icon on the button. 
Please tell me why?

Comment: Your selector should be `.button .icon`

Answer (score 2):

set style rules for the `.icon` class, see below code:

```css
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.button .icon {
    background: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/281/281769.svg) no-repeat;
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px
}  
.button .span {
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<button class="button"><span class="icon"></span>Button</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the icon as a class ".icon" and nesting it inside the button.  Style as needed from there.

```
.button .icon {
background: url(gmail-icon.png) no-repeat;
float: left;
width: 10px;
height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work with dot. Anyway my html and png file are in the same folder on pc. I don't know what's wrong

Comment: @D.Anna Have you tried setting a background size? e.g: `background-size: contain`

Comment: @D.Anna Yeaaaa! Let's pop the champagne

Answer (score 0):

you have forget the quots ""
and change :icon to .icon

Try this one:

```
.button .icon {
    background: url("gmail-icon.png") no-repeat;
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **content** instead of **background**

```
.icon {
   content: url("gmail-icon.png");
   float: left;
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   margin-right: 10px;
}
```